# Laço For não inicia com o Array

Tags: array, actionscript-3

Sou novo no AS3, e estou tentando criar um jogo para um curso que estou fazendo, mas estou com problemas para iniciar um laço que deve testar a colisão entre dois objetos chamados pelo AS3.

Como os objetos são chamados dinamicamente pelo AS3, estou inserindo-os numa `array` para referenciá-los, e funciona bem quando os identifico pelo número fixo na `array`, porém quero que ele possa testar com todos os objetos na `array`, e o resultado é que o laço nem sequer inicia.

Como não queria que ele fizesse os testes sem necessidades, coloquei o laço após um `if` para verificar se existiam objetos na `array`, e achei que o `if` que não funcionava, então inseri alguns comandos `trace`, e logo percebi que ele entrava no `if`, mas simplesmente não iniciava o laço `for`.

Laço For que não está funcionando:
[image: Laço FOR que não funciona]

Resultado na saída:
[image: Resultado na saída]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julgo que o problema está na declaração do for:

```
for(alvo = 0; alvo >= lastEnemy; alvo++)
```

julgo que deveria ser:

```
for(alvo = 0; alvo <= lastEnemy; alvo++)
```

ou:

```
for(alvo = 0; alvo < lastEnemy; alvo++)
```

`alvo >= lastEnemy` é falso logo na entrada do loop

Answer (score 2):

Você parece estar não estar firme quanto à forma que o laço `for` funciona. Recapitulando:

```
for ( iniciação ; condição de permanência ; passo ao final ) { corpo }
```

- iniciação: código a ser executado **antes** de iniciar o laço. Ele **sempre** executa, independentemente da condição estar ou não satisfeita.
- condição de permanência: teste a ser executado **antes** de entrar no corpo. Ele **sempre** testa, inclusive antes de entrar no corpo pela primeira vez. Se o resultado for `true`, ele entra no corpo, se for `false` ele não entra e segue para a próxima instrução (i.e. aquela depois do `for`).
- corpo: código que é executado múltiplas vezes, até que a condição de permanência se torne `false` ou que se saia abruptamente através de um `break`, `return` ou em caso de exceção.
- passo ao final: código a ser executado **depois** do corpo. Se o corpo terminar normalmente, ou se a instrução `continue` for usada, esse passo será executado logo em seguida. Ele ocorre **antes** da condição de permanência ser testada de novo.

Vendo seu código, me parece que sua intenção é percorrer toda a lista de objetos, certo? Desse modo, seu alvo deve seguir do primeiro índice na lista até o último. Como já sabe, ActionScript, a indexação começa do zero, de modo que o primeiro índice (iniciação) está correto. O passo também está correto (incrementar um no índice) e o índice final (`lastEnemy`) também - pois ele é o tamanho da lista menos um. O problema está na condição de permanência, então.

Como sumarizado na [resposta do @ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4830/215), sua condição de permanência (`alvo >= lastEnemy`) é falsa antes mesmo de iniciar o loop (já que a lista de objetos é maior que zero, confome testado por seu `if` - caso contrário você teria um loop infinito). Isso me leva a crer que você estava tentando criar uma **condição de parada** em vez disso, estou certo? De todo modo, essa condição de parada não estaria correta, uma vez que ele iria sair logo que `alvo` fosse igual a `lastEnemy` (e você quer que ele saia logo **após** isso). Ou seja, parar se `alvo > lastEnemy`.

A solução então é negar a condição de parada [corrigida], para se obter a condição de permanência. `!(alvo > lastEnemy)` que é equivalente a `alvo <= lastEnemy`. Dessa forma, ele vai **continuar no loop** enquanto `alvo` for menor ou igual a `lastEnemy`, e sair tão logo essa condição se torne falsa.